# How to put a wordpress blog onto a ColdFusion web page

Tags: wordpress, coldfusion

Is there a way to add take the posts from Wordpress and put them onto a ColdFusion web page?  What I have have for a client now is a ColdFusion site, with a separate section of the site being Wordpress so that the content can be edited.  I already have Wordpress set up with the ColdFusion site.

What I need to do is grab the blog posts created in Wordpress and display them on the front page of the ColdFusion site.  I was wondering if anyone might know how this might be done.

Comment: Look at [cffeed](http://cfdocs.org/cffeed).

Comment: I've never used it but WordPress has an API, and this looks like the method to fetch a post: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts. It'd be a place to start, anyhow.

Comment: Using the WP API ties it to that platform - using the RSS/Atom feed enables the functionality to work with a range of blogs/software.

Comment: I didn't say my suggestion was *instead* of yours, Peter. Anyway, we're not answering questions the person might have in the future, we're asking the question they're asking right now, which is clearly to do with WordPress (see the title, content and tagging). And seen in that light, I think suggesting looking at the API that is purpose-built for their requirement is probably a reasonable suggestion, yes?

Comment: Aside from what Adam and Peter have suggested...if you host the WordPress site on your server, you have access to the database. You could simply use `<cfquery>` to get the latest posts...maybe even copy some of the queries from the WordPress code itself.